# Saving multiple XML files to array using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I am currently new to XML and AJAX and im just having difficulty with a few things. I am trying to parse and save 2 XML files to separate arrays and then print them out in my HTML file. I have saved them into the array, but for some reason it's not working? I have been reading and researching this topic but still struggling with this whole concept. Would anyone be able to tell me what im doing wrong? :( Thanks in advance for the help I really, really appreciate it! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var cat, c_id, c_name;
var prod, p_id, p_name, p_cid;
function loadXMLDocs()
{
loadXMLDoc("categories.xml", "Categories");
loadXMLDoc("products.xml", "Products");
}

function loadXMLDoc(url, element)
{
var xmlhttp;
var i, x, xx;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //txt="<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName(element);

    if (element == "Categories") {
      cat = x;
    }
    if (element == "Products") {
      prod = x;
    }

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + "<tr>";

      xx=cat[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryName");
      c_name = xx;
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch {
            document.write("doesnt work")
          }
        }
    xx=prod[i].getElementsByTagName("ProductName");
    p_name = xx;
      {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
          catch {
            document.write("doesnt work")
          }
        }
      txt=txt + "</tr>";
      }
    txt=txt + "</table>";
    document.getElementById('txtxmlInfo').innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Product List</h2>
<div id="txtxmlInfo">
<button type="button" onclick=loadXMLDoc"(categories.xml", "Categories)";>Get Products</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear Ben, show us what have you tried.

Comment: It may help to make your question more clear if you post some code showing what you are trying to do. Or go more into detail: Where *exactly* are you struggeling? It must be more than myarray[0] = myxml; isn't it? ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, I accidentally posted the question without the code!! The code has been included in the edit